# How to limit a CSS class effect to the HTML element's length?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add CSS classes to an HTML element in Angular.js app, but I want to limit it's effect to the length of the text. However its overflowing through the entire length of the line. Please check the JS bin link.
https://jsbin.com/yiwenesapo/1/edit?html,
Below is the snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <style>
        .test{
            background-color:#eeeeee;
            color:black;
        }
    </style>
<h1 class="test">Sales Order App</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are asking about word wrapping..??

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline` to css. See https://jsfiddle.net/zh9ge8fm/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` to .test class

Answer (score 0):

by default,`h1` element have `display:block` so get the entire(100%) line space.

so you can set width for it:

```
.test {
    width: 300px;<--------Added
    //more code
}
```

```css
.test{
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    color:black;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="test">Sales Order App</h1>
```

**OR**

Change `display:block`(default) to `display:inline-block` :

```css
.test {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    color:black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="test">Sales Order App</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear about what are you referring to, but my hunch is that you are looking for one or more of these four properties:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

OR

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: no-wrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because by default display of the element will be set to block which takes the complete width of viewport and complete height of element unless u dont specify any of these properties in css. So for the css to effect only text area you need to set `display` property to `inline` or `inline-block`  Here is the snippet...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <style>
  .test{
   background-color:#32CD32;
      color:black;
          display: inline-block;
  }
 </style>
<h1> Sales Order App</h1>
  <h1 class="test">This </h1><span> has the css peoperty only to the element not for the complete row</span>
</body>
</html>
```